# Minimal regex engine

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, regex, reinventing-the-wheel

A few months back, I posted a [state machine](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/201528/finite-state-automata) for review. Thanks to the feedback, I was able to greatly simplify the implementation. I am posting the revised version, together with the Regex class which calls it.

I think I'm mainly looking for feedback on structure. The relationship between my `Node` class and `StateMachine` class feels a little tangled; I'm not always sure which method ought to belong to which class. I think the way I communicate the next token of my lexer is also cumbersome.

**`state_machine.py`**

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.children = set()

    def empty(self):
        return self.value == ''

    def add_child(self, other):
        self.children.add(other)

    def find_parent_of_terminal(self, terminal):
        """
        We assume that there shall only be one node leading to the terminal
        and that there is only one terminal
        """
        visited = set()
        to_explore = {self}
        while to_explore:
            current = to_explore.pop()
            visited.add(current)
            if terminal in current.children:
                # If this fails, then there is a bug in union, concat, or kleene
                assert len(current.children) == 1
                return current
            to_explore.update({node for node in current.children 
                               if node not in visited})
        return None

    def leads_to(self, value):
        """
        Return True iff argument can be reached by traversing empty nodes
        """
        return bool(self._get_node_if_reachable(value))

    def _get_node_if_reachable(self, value):
        for node in self.children:
            while node and node.empty():
                if node == value:
                    return node
                node = node._get_node_if_reachable(value)
        return None

    def __repr__(self):
        result = '{} : ['.format(self.value)
        for node in self.children:
            result += str(node.value) + ', '
        result += ']\n'

        return result


def EmptyNode():
    return Node('')


class StateMachine:

    def __init__(self):
        self.initial = EmptyNode()
        self.terminal = EmptyNode()

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.initial)

    @staticmethod
    def from_string(source):
        dfa = StateMachine()
        nodes = [Node(char) for char in source]

        dfa.initial.add_child(nodes[0])
        for i in range(len(source) - 1):
            nodes[i].add_child(nodes[i + 1])
        nodes[-1].add_child(dfa.terminal)
        return dfa

    @staticmethod
    def from_set(chars):
        dfa = StateMachine()
        first = EmptyNode()
        penultimate = EmptyNode()
        dfa.initial.children = {first}

        for char in chars:
            char_node = Node(char)
            first.add_child(char_node)
            char_node.add_child(penultimate)

        penultimate.add_child(dfa.terminal)
        return dfa

    def concat(self, other):
        other.initial.find_parent_of_terminal(other.terminal).children = {self.terminal}
        self.initial.find_parent_of_terminal(self.terminal).children = other.initial.children

        return self

    def union(self, other):
        self.initial.children.update(other.initial.children)

        this_last = self.initial.find_parent_of_terminal(self.terminal)
        other_last = other.initial.find_parent_of_terminal(other.terminal)
        empty_node = EmptyNode()
        empty_node.add_child(self.terminal)
        this_last.children = {empty_node}
        other_last.children = {empty_node}
        return self

    def kleene(self):
        penultimate_node = self.initial.find_parent_of_terminal(self.terminal)
        dummy = EmptyNode()
        penultimate_node.children = {dummy}
        dummy.add_child(self.terminal)
        penultimate_node.add_child(self.initial)
        self.initial.add_child(dummy)
        return self

    def _get_next_state(self, nodes, value, visited=None):
        if visited is None:
            visited = set()
        result = set()
        for node in nodes:
            visited.add(node)
            for child in node.children:
                if child.empty() and child not in visited:
                    result.update(self._get_next_state([child], value, visited))
                elif child.value == value:
                    result.add(child)
        return result

    def is_match(self, nodes):
        for node in nodes:
            if node .leads_to(self.terminal):
                return True
        return False

    def match(self, source):
        """
        Match a target string by simulating a NFA
        :param source: string to match
        :return: Matched part of string, or None if no match is found
        """
        result = ''
        last_match = None
        current = {self.initial}
        for char in source:
            next_nodes = self._get_next_state(current, char)
            if next_nodes:
                current = next_nodes
                result += char

                if self.is_match(current):
                    last_match = result
            else:
                break

        if self.is_match(current):
            last_match = result
        return last_match
```

**`regex.py`**

```
import collections
import enum
import string


from state_machine import StateMachine


class Token(enum.Enum):
    METACHAR = 0
    CHAR = 1
    ERROR = 2


class LexResult(collections.namedtuple('LexResult', ['token', 'lexeme'])):
    def __bool__(self):
        return self.token != Token.ERROR


class RegexLexer(object):
    metachars = '-|[]^().*'

    def __init__(self, pattern: str):
        self._pattern = pattern
        self._pos = 0
        self._stack = []

    def peek(self) -> LexResult:
        if self._pos >= len(self._pattern):
            return LexResult(Token.ERROR, '')
        next_char = self._pattern[self._pos]
        if next_char in self.metachars:
            token = Token.METACHAR
        else:
            token = Token.CHAR
        return LexResult(token, next_char)

    def _eat_token_type(self, token: Token) -> LexResult:
        next_match = self.peek()
        if next_match.token != token:
            return LexResult(Token.ERROR, next_match.lexeme)
        self._pos += 1
        return next_match

    def _eat_token(self, match: LexResult) -> LexResult:
        next_match = self.peek()
        if next_match == match:
            self._pos += 1
            return next_match
        return LexResult(Token.ERROR, next_match.lexeme)

    def mark(self):
        self._stack.append(self._pos)

    def clear(self):
        self._stack.pop()

    def backtrack(self):
        self._pos = self._stack.pop()

    def eat_char(self, char=''):
        if char:
            return self._eat_token(LexResult(Token.CHAR, char))
        return self._eat_token_type(Token.CHAR)

    def eat_metachar(self, metachar):
        return self._eat_token(LexResult(Token.METACHAR, metachar))


class Regex(object):
    CHARACTERS = string.printable

    def __init__(self, pattern: str):
        """
        Initialize regex by compiling provided pattern
        """
        self._lexer = RegexLexer(pattern)
        self._state_machine = self.parse()

    def match(self, text: str) -> str:
        """
        Match text according to provided pattern.
        Returns matched substring if a match was found,
        or None otherwise
        """
        assert self._state_machine
        return self._state_machine.match(text)

    def parse(self):
        nfa = self.parse_simple_re()
        if not nfa:
            return None
        while True:
            self._lexer.mark()
            if not self._lexer.eat_metachar('|'):
                self._lexer.backtrack()
                return nfa
            next_nfa = self.parse_simple_re()
            if not next_nfa:
                self._lexer.backtrack()
                return nfa
            nfa = nfa.union(next_nfa)
            self._lexer.clear()

    def parse_simple_re(self):
        """
        <simple-re> = <basic-re>+
        """
        nfa = self.parse_basic_re()
        if not nfa:
            return None

        while True:
            next_nfa = self.parse_basic_re()
            if not next_nfa:
                break
            nfa = nfa.concat(next_nfa)
        return nfa

    def parse_basic_re(self):
        """
        <elementary-re> "*" | <elementary-re> "+" | <elementary-re>
        """
        nfa = self.parse_elementary_re()
        if not nfa:
            return None
        next_match = self._lexer.peek()
        if not next_match or next_match.token != Token.METACHAR:
            return nfa
        if next_match.lexeme == '*':
            self._lexer.eat_metachar('*')
            return nfa.kleene()
        if next_match.lexeme == '+':
            self._lexer.eat_metachar('+')
            return nfa.union(nfa.kleene())
        return nfa

    def parse_elementary_re(self):
        """
        <elementary-RE> = <group> | <any> | <char> | <set>
        :return: DFA
        """
        self._lexer.mark()
        nfa = self.parse_group()
        if nfa:
            self._lexer.clear()
            return nfa

        self._lexer.backtrack()
        if self._lexer.eat_metachar('.'):
            return StateMachine.from_set({x for x in self.CHARACTERS})

        char = self._lexer.eat_char()
        if char:
            return StateMachine.from_string(char.lexeme)

        set_chars = self.parse_set()
        if not set_chars:
            return None
        return StateMachine.from_set(set_chars)

    def parse_group(self):
        """
        <group> = "(" <RE> ")"
        :return: DFA
        """
        if not self._lexer.eat_metachar('('):
            return None
        state_machine = self.parse()
        if not state_machine:
            return None
        if not self._lexer.eat_metachar(')'):
            return None
        return state_machine

    def parse_range(self) -> {str}:
        """
        <range> = <CHAR> "-" <CHAR>
        """
        first = self._lexer.eat_char()
        if not first:
            return set()

        if not self._lexer.eat_metachar('-'):
            return set()

        last = self._lexer.eat_char()
        if not last:
            return set()

        return {chr(x) for x in range(ord(first.lexeme), ord(last.lexeme) + 1)}

    def parse_set_item(self) -> {str}:
        """
        <set item> = <range> | <char>
        """
        self._lexer.mark()
        set_item = self.parse_range()
        if set_item:
            self._lexer.clear()
            return set_item
        self._lexer.backtrack()
        next_item = self._lexer.eat_char()
        return {next_item.lexeme} if next_item else set()

    def parse_set_items(self) -> {str}:
        """
        <set items> = <set item>+
        """
        items = self.parse_set_item()
        if not items:
            return set()
        next_items = self.parse_set_item()
        while next_items:
            items.update(next_items)
            next_items = self.parse_set_item()
        return items

    def parse_positive_set(self) -> {str}:
        if not self._lexer.eat_metachar('['):
            return set()
        set_items = self.parse_set_items()
        if not set_items:
            return set()
        if not self._lexer.eat_metachar(']'):
            return set()
        return set_items

    def parse_negative_set(self) -> {str}:
        if not self._lexer.eat_metachar('['):
            return set()
        if not self._lexer.eat_metachar('^'):
            return set()
        set_items = self.parse_set_items()
        if not set_items:
            return set()
        if not self._lexer.eat_metachar(']'):
            return set()
        return set(string.printable).difference(set_items)

    def parse_set(self) -> {str}:
        """
        Parse something like [a-z9] and return the set of allowed characters
        """
        self._lexer.mark()
        set_items = self.parse_positive_set()
        if set_items:
            self._lexer.clear()
            return set_items
        self._lexer.backtrack()
        return self.parse_negative_set()
```

Finally, a small set of unit tests to show usage:

```
import unittest
from state_machine import StateMachine
from regex import Regex


class TestStateMachine(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_union(self):
        state_machine = StateMachine.from_string('abc')
        state_machine = state_machine.union(StateMachine.from_string('def'))

        self.assertEqual(state_machine.match('abc'), 'abc')
        self.assertEqual(state_machine.match('def'), 'def')
        self.assertIsNone(state_machine.match('de'))

    def test_kleene(self):
        state_machine = StateMachine.from_string('abc')
        state_machine = state_machine.kleene()

        self.assertEqual(state_machine.match(''), '')
        self.assertEqual(state_machine.match('abc'), 'abc')
        self.assertEqual(state_machine.match('abcabc'), 'abcabc')
        self.assertEqual(state_machine.match('abcDabc'), 'abc')

    def test_concat(self):
        state_machine = StateMachine.from_string('ab')
        state_machine = state_machine.concat(StateMachine.from_string('cd'))

        self.assertEqual(state_machine.match('abcd'), 'abcd')
        self.assertEqual(state_machine.match('abcde'), 'abcd')
        self.assertIsNone(state_machine.match('abc'))


class TestRegex(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_identifier_regex(self):
        regex = Regex('[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*')
        self.assertEqual(regex.match('a'), 'a')
        self.assertFalse(regex.match('0'))
        self.assertTrue(regex.match('a0'))
        self.assertEqual(regex.match('a0_3bd'), 'a0_3bd')
        self.assertEqual(regex.match('abd-43'), 'abd')

    def test_parentheses(self):
        regex = Regex('d(ab)*')
        self.assertEqual(regex.match('d'), 'd')
        self.assertEqual(regex.match('dab'), 'dab')
        self.assertEqual(regex.match('daa'), 'd')
        self.assertEqual(regex.match('dabab'), 'dabab')

    def test_union(self):
        regex = Regex('(ab*d)|(AG)')
        self.assertEqual(regex.match('adG'), 'ad')
        self.assertEqual(regex.match('AGfe'), 'AG')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Hello, this looks like a very interesting question and a well written piece of code! By any chance, would you have any small example that could be used to test your code ?

Comment: @Josay See edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yay! You ran `flake8` and followed PEP-8. Nice clean code.

```
    self.assertEqual(state_machine.match('abc'), 'abc')
```

Ummm, this is arguably backwards.
Convention for xUnit in many languages is to `assertEqual(expected, computed)`.
It can affect how the diagnostic output is displayed for a failure.

```
    state_machine = state_machine.union(StateMachine.from_string('def'))
```

Choosing the name `union` for your public API is perhaps slightly confusing.
"Union" is drawn from [set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory),
while "alternation" is the term the regex literature tends to use for `|`.

```
    state_machine = StateMachine.from_string('abc')
```

The class name is perfectly clear, it's great.
For a local variable that we'll be using a bunch, `sm` would have sufficed.
You already have a line that verifies that `.from_string()` doesn't blow up, so
consider combining two assignments on a single line:

```
    sm = StateMachine.from_string('abc').kleene()
```

The `Regex` class is wonderfully straightforward.
Pat yourself on the back.

The `peek` method in the lexer is perhaps a little on the tricky side,
and would benefit from comments
about when we consume something or not.
I'm looking for invariants on `pos` and the `stack`.
I like the `assert` in `find_parent_of_terminal`, and its comment.

```
        to_explore.update({node for node in current.children 
                           if node not in visited})
```

That's just `set` difference, yes? `children - visited`

Overall, looks good. Ship it!